# Issue with looping a javascript animation : Jsanim

Tags: javascript, animation, loops

I am using jsAnim for some simple animations .

http://jsanim.com/

I have created a simple javascript function -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var man = new jsAnimManager(); 

function animation1() {
    shroom = document.getElementById("mushroom2");

    man.registerPosition("mushroom2");

    var monster =  $("#mushroom2");
var offset = monster.offset();
var l=offset.left;
var r= offset.top;


    shroom.setPosition(l,r);

    var anim = man.createAnimObject("mushroom2");

    anim.add({property: Prop.position, to: new Pos(l+100,r+400), 
           duration: 1000,ease:jsAnimEase.parabolicNeg });
}

</script>
```

I have similarly defined another animation2() function .

The animation works well independently .
However I am trying to loop this animation inside a for loop.

```
for( var i=1, l=data.length; i < 6 ; i++) 
            {

                  if  ((i==1 )||(i==3)) animation1(); else animation2();


            }
```

But what I observe is that the animation happens only for i=5 ( i.e .. after the loop stops executing ) . There is no animation for i = 1-4 .

Is this some threading issue ? Do I need to use some form of threads or sleeper or something ?

Please help .

I wish to make the object take a few different paths in stages .

Comment: What's the exact issue? Can you show a fiddle? Have you already tried adding `onComplete:function(){animation1();}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the animation functions are being executed virtually instantaneously.  Because the jsanim library doesn't have queue functionality, the only animation you will see in this case is the last one (because each time the next animation is executed, the last one is aborted).

But it does have an `onComplete` callback handler, so a queue is easy enough to implement.  You need a queue array that is visible to all functions:

```
var animationQueue = [];
```

Then change your for loop to add the functions to the queue instead of executing them:

```
for( var i=1; i<6; i++)  {
    if  (i%2==1)    //if i is odd number
        animationQueue .push(animation1); 
    else            //else i is even number
        animationQueue .push(animation2); 
}
nextAnimation();
```

Also notice that I used `i%2==1`.  I am assuming you want odd numbers here when you say `if(i==1 || i==3)`. The nextAnimation() function could look something like this:

```
function nextAnimation() {
    if(animationQueue.length) 
        animationQueue.shift()();
}
```

And lastly, you need to add the `onComplete` option in your call to the animation:

```
anim.add({
    property: Prop.position,
    to: new Pos(l+100,r+400),
    duration: 1000,
    ease:jsAnimEase.parabolicNeg,
    onComplete: nextAnimation
});
```

Hope that gets you onto the right track!

Comment: Is there any other javascript library that you prefer and which has more features and easy to use for 2d web animations ?

Comment: There are several good ones out there (of which Jsanim is one of), and it depends on what kind of animations you want to do, but I also like the $fx animation library (http://fx.inetcat.com/). It's pretty easy to use and really small (4Kb). Like Jsanim it doesn't need any other libraries (like jQuery or MooTools).  If you are already using jQuery, you can do animation with that also, but I wouldn't recommend it if animations are all you need.  If you'd like a more detailed answer, consider starting a new question so you can get more opinions.  Hope that helps!